# How to access private variable from Superclass in Subclass without changing Superclass? (Java)

Tags: java

I'm doing a homework for class right now and it requires me to use private variables from a superclass in one of its subclasses, but I don't know how to. I found a lot of info on changing the superclass which would work, but the assignment says that I'm not allowed to edit the superclass, just its subclasses. Is this even possible?

For context, the assignment is on weekly earnings of different employees and printing out their info(first and last name, employee id, position, and earnings). The first name, last name, and employee id are private and I need to override a method in the superclass in the subclass.

Code from superclass:

```
public String toString(){
   return "Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + ", ID: " + employeeId;
}
```

Code from subclass(that I'm writing)

```
//  Override public String toString() here
/*public String toString(){
   return ("Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + ", ID: " + employeeId + " Position: Boss");
}*/
```

I tried using get and set within the subclass, but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really need to modify the superclass variables or just access the `toString()`, i.e. print them out?

Comment: Isn't the assignment just asking you to call the super class's `toString` and append to that? Or do I not understand the assignment?

Comment: Why not just `return super.toString() + "Position: Boss);`?

Comment: @UnholySheep the assignment requires the toString() method to be overriden and for more info to be added so i couldn't just call it normally.

Comment: `private` fields are exactly meant to be private, that is, not *known* by any other class. but the superclass should have getter methods to retrieve the names and ID (for example if the output of `toString()` isn't appropriate)

Comment: @NeverendingFlame42 Please [edit] your question to include the original assignment (unchanged) you have. Calling the base method like [`super.toString()` as mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323055/how-to-access-private-variable-from-superclass-in-subclass-without-changing-supe#comment131212549_74323055) might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to `toString()` output, you could use `super.toString()`.

```
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " earnings: " +earnings;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection API is here to help. In your inheriting class, use:

```
Field field = super
  .getClass()
  .getDeclaredField("firstName");
field.setAccessible(true);
String firstname = (String) field.get(super);
```